# Update the owner of SQL Server database and agent

Tags: sql-server, powershell

There are a large number of objects in SQL Server that are owned by people who have resigned.

We need a script to change the ownership of all of these objects to SA.

Can anyone help with this script?

Also how we can test it before we run it in production server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2016 Change Object Owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680280/sql-server-2016-change-object-owner)

Comment: You need to provide at least a starter script made by you so we will know where to start depending on what you have understood so far.

Comment: @JonP
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_manage_jobs_by_login
    action = N'REASSIGN',  
    current_owner_login_name = N'xxxx',  
    new_owner_login_name = N'sa';
 i have done this for agent job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the owner of SQl agent job

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_manage_jobs_by_login
@action = N'REASSIGN',  
@current_owner_login_name = N'currentowner',  
@new_owner_login_name = N'sa';
```

Change the owner of SQl Database

```
use master
go
select 'use [' + db.name+']; exec sp_changedbowner [sa];' from 
sys.databases db left join sys.server_principals sp
on db.owner_sid=sp.sid
where suser_sname(owner_sid)='current owner'
```